# ElasticSearch match multiple fields with different values

Tags: elasticsearch, field, match

I can actually perform a simple match search with this:

```
query: {match: {searchable: {query:search}}}
```

This works well, my searchable field is analyzed in my mapping.

Now I want to perform a search on multiple fields: 1 string, and all other are numeric.

My mapping:

```
mappings dynamic: 'false' do
        indexes :searchable, analyzer: "custom_index_analyzer", search_analyzer: "custom_search_analyzer"
        indexes :year, type: "integer"
        indexes :country_id, type: "integer"
        indexes :region_id, type: "integer"
        indexes :appellation_id, type: "integer"
        indexes :category_id, type: "integer"
      end

def as_indexed_json(options={}) 
      as_json(
        only: [:searchable, :year, :country_id, :region_id, :appellation_id, :category_id]
      ) 
    end
```

I have tried this:

```
query: {
                    filtered: {
                      query: {
                        match: {
                          searchable: search
                        }
                      },
                      filter: {
                        term: {
                          country_id: "1"
                        },
                        term: {
                          region_id: "2"
                        },
                        term: {
                          appellation_id: "34"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  sort: {
                    _score: {
                      order: :desc
                    }, 
                    year: {
                      order: :desc, 
                      ignore_unmapped: true
                    }
                  },
                  size:100
```

It works well but it will give me 100 results in all cases, from the appellation_id sent (34), even if the searchable field is very far from the text search.

I have also tried a BOOL query:

```
  self.search(query: {
                bool: {
                  must: [
                    {
                      match: {
                            country_id: "1"
                          },
                          match: {
                            region_id: "2"
                          },
                          match: {
                            appellation_id: "34"
                          },
                          match: {
                            searchable: search
                          }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              sort: {
                _score: {
                  order: :desc
                }, 
                year: {
                  order: :desc, 
                  ignore_unmapped: true
                }
              },
              size:100
            )
```

But It will give me all results matching the searchable field and don't take care of the appellation_id wanted.

My goal is to get the best results and performance and ask ES to give me all data from country_id=X, region_id=Y, appellation_id=Z and finally perform a match on this set of results with the searchable field... and don't obtain results to far from reality with the searchable text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you may know elasticsearch `match` query returns result based on a [relevance score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html). You can try to use `term` query instead of match for an exact term match. Also I guess your bool query structure must be like :

```
bool: {
      must: [
          { match: {
                country_id: "1"
              }},
          {match: {
            region_id: "2"
          }},
          {match: {
            appellation_id: "34"
          }},
          {match: {
            searchable: search
          }}
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Alpert, It's working well with your new structure (double {} around match). I also tried with **term** instead of **match** and get the same scores. So thanks. My only problem is for the searchable field (the mapping uses ngrams): how to stop results if terms found are not what is expected ? For example, searching "beaulieu" will give 2 nice results and 98 very very far from this word. Scoring jumped from 11 to 2... but it depends terms searched.

Comment: I can use the min_score param but it's an arbitrary pattern.

Comment: Check if minimum_should_match will work for you: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html

Comment: minimum_should_match seems to not work in a "match" included in a bool query.